# Does Entity Framework 6 support .NET 4.0?

Tags: .net-4.0, entity-framework-6

I believe Entity Framework 6 is intended for .NET 4.5. I'm wanting to use it for a Visual Studio 2010 project, so .NET 4.5 isn't available.

Does it support .NET 4.0 and hence Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: Since all major Windows release supports .NET 4.5 (XP/Server 2003 are going to phase out soon), there is little hope for EF 6 to support non-.NET 4.5. Visual Studio 2013 is going to launch in only a few days, so Visual Studio 2010 becomes "too old".

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Entity Framework 6 does support .NET 4.0.  You should update your version of NuGet then try again.  You can find the download at http://www.nuget.org/.  I successfully downloaded EntityFramework 6.0.0-rc1 from the main nuget.org feed from an application targeting .NET 4.0

Comment: You're right! I think I got this mixed up with Enterprise Library 6. This isn't the first time I've done that!

Comment: Beware that .NET 4.0 implementation of EF6 (example 6.1.3) does not seem to implement some async components like IDbAsyncEnumerable  which seems to be available when your project targets .NET 4.5 or later. For further info check  http://stackoverflow.com/a/40295378/378115

Answer (score 2):

[Entity Framework Version History](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574253.aspx)

EF6 This release can be used in Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2010 (runtime only) to write applications that target .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 1):

As of writing, on October 2018, latest EF 6.2.0 still supports .NET 4.0 and works very fine in Visual Studio 2010.