# Entity Framework can't find version. Even though DLL's, Connector and frameworks are installed

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio

I'm trying to add a `MySQL` database to my `MVC` project through the `Entity Framework`. I've already installed the `Connector` and found my database but then I get this message:

[image]

What am I missing?

**Edit**

I've found this question about the same problem. [Link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22031269/enable-entity-framework-6-for-mysql-c-in-winforms-of-microsoft-visual-studio).
And I've followed the guide, and added the MySQL.Data, MySQL.Data.Entities, MySQL.Web and EntityFramework NuGet packages. But I still have the same problem.

Also changed the `<entityFramework>` tag as suggested in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I works in any other project than this one. So made a new project with the database model and copied the code over.