# Can't find a MySQL connection for entity framework 6

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I want to use Entity Framework with MySQL

(with reference to [Enable Entity Framework 6 for MySql (C#) in WinForms of Microsoft Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22031269/enable-entity-framework-6-for-mysql-c-in-winforms-of-microsoft-visual-studio))

But i could not found "MySQL Database"

[image]
.

How can I add a MySQL? Thanks

(I had to install connector, In the past I have used the entity framework in the same environment)

Comment: have you installed MySqlConnector?

Comment: Yes! I installed Connector!

Comment: What happens, if you click on the drop box at the bottom of the form? Do you get an option for MySql?

Comment: I've click, but I could not find anything.