# Connecting to MySQL db using Entity Framework ADO.NET error

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've been trying to connect to a MySQL database using EF6 in Visual Studio 2015 and following the instructions from an answer found here: [Enable Entity Framework 6 for MySql (C#) in WinForms of Microsoft Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22031269/enable-entity-framework-6-for-mysql-c-in-winforms-of-microsoft-visual-studio), I was able to get passed most of my issues. However, after setting up the connection, testing it, and selecting the correct db on that server connection, when it gets to the step of generating the tables for me to import into my edmx file, it just closes out. I don't really know how else to explain it, the wizard closes out and I'm back at the main VS screen. No error message, no nothing, it just cancels out. What could be causing this?

Some additional information:

-I have to establish an open connection to the server first before I can connect to it on my machine (we're using FortiClient).

-It's a MySQL database, I followed all the steps in the linked page to get it to work with VS already.

Comment: I had this same problem. The only fix I found was to use EF5 instead.