# adding ADO.NET Entity Model crash

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio

I'm trying to add ADO.NET Entity Model to a new project.

Chose EF Designer from database, chose the database (on another server, tried 2 server one with mysql 5.6 and one with 5.7) and press continue and the the flow crash. tried it several times with different server and versions.

I installed all the latest versions of mySQL connection and EF.

Checked if there are error in the event viewer but couldn't fine errors or warnings at all.

Comment: You may find a solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22031269/enable-entity-framework-6-for-mysql-c-in-winforms-of-microsoft-visual-studio  and http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71427

Comment: This is not my problem, i wish it was,  the flow crash before I get to this window,  the step before when I press next it crashes

Comment: What  is visual studio  version , EF version you use?

Comment: visual studio 2015, EF 6.1.3

Answer (score 0):

I had same mistake. The reason was in the difference between mysql-connector-net version and MySQL.Data.Entity version. I uninstalled mysql-connector-net, then installed correct version, and the wizard started to work normally.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I tried this today. I like to share my solution working for VS 2017.
First install MySQL for Visual Studio. Then install the MySQL Connector 6.10.7.
Now you are able to do everything else:
Inside your project install some NuGets MySQL.Data and the MySQL.Entity: Both with version 6.10.7. The VS 2017 does not close anymore and the model window is opened.

Answer (score 0):

I Hint also first install MySQL for Visual Studio. Then install the connector. This solves two issues: You can use MySQL in Visual Studio and you connect stable to a database.

Please, ensure what 3per mentions: MySQL.Data and MySQL.Data.Entity has to the same version.

Hope this helped others a lot.