# Entity Framework execute RawSql on MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using `EntityFramework` to connect to a `MySql` server.

I have a method which inserts many objects in the database. For this, i am generating an SQL script, which i execute it using `dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(script)` method.

This workflow works ok when the `EntityFramework` was connected to `MS SQL Server`.

Now, after i moved it to `MySql`, it throws error when executing the script.

> Incorrect syntax near '`'.

**Important**

The script had been generated to match `MySql` syntax. If i run that script in `MySQL Workbench`, the query is executed successfully.

I think that `EntityFramework` is trying to parse the script i am sending, but in the `MS SQL` language.

Here is the exception Stack Trace:

```
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass59.<ExecuteStoreCommand>b__58()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass59.<ExecuteStoreCommand>b__57()
at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand(TransactionalBehavior transactionalBehavior, String commandText, Object[] parameters)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior transactionalBehavior, String sql, Object[] parameters)
at System.Data.Entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior transactionalBehavior, String sql, Object[] parameters)
at System.Data.Entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(String sql, Object[] parameters)
at AppFormApp.Domain.EntityFramework.AppFormAppDatabaseService.<InsertAllObjectsAsync>d__1.MoveNext() in F:\GitRoot\AppFormApp\AppFormApp\AppFormApp.Domain\EntityFramework\AppFormAppDatabaseService.cs:line 120
```

**UPDATE**

This is the `MySQL` query generated

```
INSERT INTO `appformapp`.`appformdata`(`Id`, `ApplicationIdentifier`, `ApplicationName`, `LastSavedDate`, `LastActivity`)
VALUES (N'59bbf577-d601-4857-aabf-84b69b2d7b75', N'APP-TMH3EI', N'Test ABV', N'2016-10-17 05:56:16', N'2016-10-17 05:56:16');
```

The Entity Framework is already working with `MySql`. The error is only triggered when using `dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(script)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable Entity Framework 6 for MySql (C#) in WinForms of Microsoft Visual Studio 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22031269/enable-entity-framework-6-for-mysql-c-in-winforms-of-microsoft-visual-studio)

Comment: you sure are using the right db context?

Comment: what is your `script` here `dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(script)` ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Entity Framework is correctly configured with `MySql`. please read the update

Comment: @Sampath check the edit