# Windows Forms C# Entity Framework 6 with MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I need to start a Windows Forms project using `C#` and `Entity Framework 6` (Database First) since I have the `MySQL` database ready.

I have searched a lot and have seen multiple posts here on `Stackoverflow` and other, (Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22031269/enable-entity-framework-6-for-mysql-c-in-winforms-of-microsoft-visual-studio), [this](http://qursaan-howto.blogspot.com/2014/07/solve-your-project-references-latest.html) and [this](https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/21680548/mysql-connector-with-ef-6)) but nothing solved my problem, and here is my problem :

I added the `EntityFramework plugin (Ver 6.2.0)` with the `MySql.Data (Ver 8.0.15)` and `MySql.Data.Entity (Ver 7.0.7-ms61)` plugins in order, i also installed `MySql for Visual Studio (Ver 1.2.8)` and `MySql Connector Net (Ver 8.0.15)` and when I select my database and check that the connection is successfully established... I get this error message :

> "Your project references the latest version of Entity Framework; however, an Entity Framework database provider compatible with this version could not be found for your data connection. Exit this wizard, install a compatible provider, and rebuild your project before performing this action".

I tried all different versions of every plugin i am adding but no luck, If i downgrade the EF version form 6 to 5... I get this message :

> "Your project references an older version on Entity Framework, To use the latest version, exit this wizard and upgrade before preforming this action."

Even If i continue with this action and clicked Next, nothing will show up or happen.

My `App.config` file after I have added all the plugins looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value=" v13.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=7.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider></providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.15.0" newVersion="8.0.15.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

And I tried replacing the `<entityFramework>` tag with this :

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

But nothing is working, I am also rebuilding after every new thing that I try, is there someone able to help me please...

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this [MySql documentation page on Entity Framework 6 Support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html) help?

Comment: @stuartd thank you, but no it **didn't** help.

Comment: Wait a couple of weeks use .net core with EF Core, you will probably have less hair loss.  I always found configuring EF6 something that of cutting one's self

Comment: Why did you leave the `System.Data.SqlClient` part in there?

Comment: @GertArnold  You mean in the `App.config` file?