# How to Upgrade to EF 6

Tags: entity-framework

Goal: use EF 6 in my computer.

Problem: I retrieve a message saying that I need to use the latest version of the project references.

Where and how should I do it?

Information:

Using VS 2013, SQL Server 2012, Windows Server 2012 standard in my computer.

[image]

Comment: nuget package manager, `Update-Package EntityFramework` would be my first guess

Comment: Dependent on .NET Framework version maybe? See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239140/does-entity-framework-6-support-net-4-0

Answer (score 0):

In `Visual Studio 2013` from `View->Other Windows` select `Package Manager Console` option and write following command:

`Update-Package EntityFramework`

Note that you need to select correct project in "Default Project ComboBox" and connect to internet, too.